# Перенос изображения svg через html при создании чат-бота в телеграмм

Tags: html, telegram-bot, svg

Программист написал код для создания бота в телеграмм. Суть бота - генерить этикетки по заданным параметрам из текста и выдавать их в формате изображения. Но столкнулись с проблемой: текст на изображении не переносится на следующую строку, а заходит за ее границы. Как это исправить?

Вот сам код:

```
<svg width="${imageInfo.width}" height="${imageInfo.height}">
    <rect width="${imageInfo.width}" height="${imageInfo.height}" fill="none" />
    <text x="10" y="50">
    <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
           Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
           Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
    </tspan>
    <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
           Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
           Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
    </tspan>
    <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
          Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
          Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
    </tspan>
```

[image: фото результата, текст обрезается]